# Как использовать useSelector в react + redux + typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

[image: ошибка]

использую useSelector выходит ошибка 
Property 'reducer' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)

Comment: Навести мышкой на state и посмотреть, какие свойства он содержит.

Comment: ничего не содержит. показан только тип state: rootstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TypeScript

- http://www.typescriptlang.org - официальный сайт TypeScript
- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html - документация по интерфейсам

## Redux

- https://redux.js.org/ - официальный сайт Redux

### redux.js.org -> рецепты -> использование совместно с TypeScript

https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#usage-with-react-redux

> ```
> interface RootState {
>   isOn: boolean
> }
> // TS infers type: (state: RootState) => boolean
> const selectIsOn = (state: RootState) => state.isOn
> // TS infers `isOn` is boolean
> const isOn = useSelector(selectIsOn)
> ```

## Как переводить веб-страницы ?

читай там https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089320/232932

Comment: что это вообще значит? как этим пользоваться?

Comment: @ИванИванов, ответ *qwabra* более "практичнее", чем предыдущие ответы.
для более ясного пониманию можете представить эту запись так: `const isOn = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.isOn);`

Answer (score 2):

Просто переопределитe `DefaultRootState` как это рекомндует `react-redux`, вот так:

```typescript
declare module 'react-redux' {
    interface DefaultRootState extends YourAppState {}
}
```

Comment: Поправил. В следующий раз [правте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1140136/edit) сами.