# Как переводить веб-страницы

Tags: faq

это общий вопрос для раздела [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

## Как переводить веб-страницы (документацию)

Comment: За стремление и наполнение информационной базы большой плюс.

Comment: мне лично не хватает понимания, когда стоит ставить метку faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это общий ответ для раздела [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

## Как переводить веб-страницы с помощью Google Переводчика

- Откройте [сайт Google Переводчика](https://translate.google.com/) на компьютере.
- Скопируйте URL и вставьте его в текстовое окно.
- Чтобы выбрать язык перевода, в правой верхней части страницы
  нажмите на стрелку вниз [image: Стрелка вниз].
- Нажмите на URL, появившийся в окне справа. После этого откроется новая вкладка с переведенным сайтом.
  Совет. Если вы используете Google Chrome, то можете настроить [перевод веб-страниц непосредственно в браузере](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl%3Den%26ref_topic%3D7439724%26co%3DGENIE.Platform%253DDesktop%26oco%3D1).

[источник](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534559?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru)

Answer (score 2):

### Как переводить веб-страницы (документацию)

1. Выучите английский язык.
2. Переведите веб-страницу (документацию)

Comment: вы правда думаете что этот ответ нужен разделу [tag:faq] ? хоть совет и дельный :)

Comment: @qwabra абсолютли!