# Как применять на сайте разные языки

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Как переводить все страницы сайта, чтобы при выборе переключателя языка, страницы менялись на выбранный язык? Есть ли готовый код? Насколько сложно самому это написать? Приведите пример такого кода.

Comment: Многие CMS умеют в разноязычность в зависимости от отдельных условий. А фразы меняются по шаблону. Есть, условно YYes и NNo, которые меняются на Да и Нет. Но если статья написана на одном языке и нужно отображать на другом, то только ручками.

Comment: Те если у меня например 10 страниц на русском мне к каждой надо создавать дубликат только на английском потом еще писать алгоритм чтобы смена работала, а если мне надо 3 языка то это на одну страницу вдобавок еще 2 страницы с двумя разными языками я правильно понимаю лол????????

Comment: И за что мне минус поставили?))

Comment: существуют системы механизированного перевода, но они крайне  несовершенны. Так что да, ручками статьи, а для интерфейса есть уже шаблоны. Даже со времён e107.

Comment: А если с помощью гугла то вообще не Варик?

Comment: не знаю, что за Варик, но цельные статьи переводят либо вручную как в Вики, либо машинально как на сайтах Мелкомягких с предупреждением. Автоматом можно только заголовки поддерживать как в Wordpress  и то только для заголовков. Естественный язык слишком сложен.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для перевода интерфейса(меню/...), основных заголовков(домашняя/контакты), кнопок(туда/сюда)

   - гугли `i18n` + имя твоего фреймворка/библиотеки, например `i18n laravel`/`i18n react`
2. Для перевода страницы с текстом пиши кнопку вида

   ```html
   <a href="https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://ya.ru">
     translate to English
   </a>
   <br>
   <a href="https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=de&u=http://ya.ru">
     ins Deutsche übersetzen
   </a>
   ```

   - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1089320/232932
   - не забудь использовать `encodeURI` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI))